# VueJS 2 Simplert only covers the component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application

A brief description is, basically when i click on a "Submit" button per say, an alert should pop out. So I'm using [Simplert](https://mazipan.github.io/vue2-simplert/) for Vue to do that.

The project I'm currently doing is a Single Page Application (SPA) so this is where the problem is. The alert only covers the component that I'm in and does not cover the whole page.

**Problem:**
[image]

Is there a way for the alert to cover the whole page?

Comment: Simply override the mask css class to set it as `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you have at least two options to solve it: one dirty and quick and the other a little bit more design oriented

#### Option 1

override the css position property of the mask:

from: `position: absolute` to: `position: fixed`

#### Option 2

Globally declare the Simplert component, since probably you will use it a lot

```
// somewhere in your main/app/bootsrap.js file
Vue.compoment('simplert', require('vue2-simplert'))
```

Now in your root component or where you have your main `<router-view>` component (if you are using vue-router):

```
// root component
<template>
<div>
    <simplert :useRadius="true" :useIcon="true" ref="simplert"/>
    <router-view></router-view> 
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   mounted () {
      this.$on('trigger:simplert', (data) => this.triggerSimplert(data)) 
   },

   methods: {
      triggerSimplert (data) {
        this.$refs.simplert.openSimplert(data)
      }
   }

}
</script>
```

Now in any component you need to trigger the modal simply do:

```
...
someMethod () {
   let obj = {
      title: 'Custom Function',
      message: 'Click close to trigger custom function',
      type: 'info',
      onClose: this.onClose
   }

   this.$emit('trigger:simplert', obj)
}
...
```

Hope this helps.